# Do Unix timestamps share the same value in different zones

Tags: unix, timestamp

Do Unix timestamps share the same value in different zones.

Basically if a computer is running in Japan under a Japanese timezone and a computer is running in UK is the unix timestamp the same for them for the particular instance in time. I believe it is as UNIX time stamp defaults to UTC.

In other words in my mobile application is it safe to calculate time differences on the client side based on the unix time stamp? It wouldn't be if the current unix time stamp was different depending on the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that two servers have their time synchronized using some NTP service.

**NOTE:**
In mysql, unix_timestamp() execution is free of local time_zone and returns result w.r.t UTC but unix_timestamp(DATE) function assumes that specified DATE is in local time_zone and thus first converts it to UTC and then returns the result.